# Duplicate class error when building android game in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityads

I'm having trouble building my android game. I get this error:

```
 Duplicate class com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig found in modules com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.2.1-runtime.jar (:UnityAds:) and com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.2.1-runtime.jar (:com.unity3d.ads.unity-ads-4.2.1:)
```

With a lot of the same type of errors (see image). I tried removing and reinstalling unity ads but that didn't work and gave me the same errors. Any fixes on how I can remove those duplicates?
[image: more errors]

Here is a full copy of my errors:
https://pastebin.com/Ma4zcMiJ

I've tried searching online and some people said I had to reinstall. I tried tat but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I had Mediation installed and that caused the errors. I deleted the MediationAdapterDependencies.xml and the errors were resolved.